# Stuck in installing a voicecloner via Python (module not found)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pytorch, module, pre-trained-model

I use Python 3.11.5

As a great Python n00b I enter this forum because I'm stuck with installing a Voice Cloner (for personal use to do a funny trick for X-mas with my family) Its this tool that i'm trying to install: https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

With a little help of chatGTP I came quite far but for some reason the downloaded datasets cant be found. Instructions of the tool state:

[Install intructions form Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai4Se.png)
So my tree looks like this:

```
(base) willem@willems-air Voice cloner % tree
.
├── demo_cli.py
├── demo_toolbox.py
├── encoder_preprocess.py
├── encoder_train.py
├── saved_models
│   └── default
│       ├── encoder.pt
│       ├── synthesizer.pt
│       └── vocoder.pt
├── synthesizer_preprocess_audio.py
├── synthesizer_preprocess_embeds.py
├── synthesizer_train.py
└── vocoder_train.py

3 directories, 11 files
```

However, when I give the command to execute the demo, I get the message that a needed module cant be found:

```
(base) willem@willems-air Voice cloner % python demo_cli.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/willem/Desktop/Voice cloner/demo_cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from encoder import inference as encoder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encoder'
```

I build a tree that (for me) looks inline with the installation instructions...(And of course i downloaded the modules without any errors)
Here also the first lines of the command demo_cli.py where you also see the path:

```
import argparse
import os
from pathlib import Path

import librosa
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import torch

from encoder import inference as encoder
from encoder.params_model import model_embedding_size as speaker_embedding_size
from synthesizer.inference import Synthesizer
from utils.argutils import print_args
from utils.default_models import ensure_default_models
from vocoder import inference as vocoder


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--enc_model_fpath", type=Path,
                        default="saved_models/default/encoder.pt",
```

I think i missed out a quite basic step here, but this far ChatGTP is looping and cant help any more, so I need a human tip i guess ;)

Thx in advance!